# A template code to execute stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Usually when it is necessary to communicate with MySQL via PHP I use a template similar to the one below (which is similar to the ones available in beginners tutorials):

```
// Exception Handler
class customException extends Exception {}

// Database Link (include file in a private directory)
function db_connect()
{
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $database = "database";

    $connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    return $connection;
}

// Template for calling common types of stored procedures:
// select a table row based on the primary key (pk)
function select_pk($connection, string $pk): array
{
    // if other database is needed
    mysqli_select_db($connection, "database1");

    // query execution
    $query = sprintf("CALL select__pk('%s')", mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $pk));
    $resource = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource);

    // prepare for next query
    mysqli_free_result($resource);      
    while(mysqli_more_results($connection)) mysqli_next_result($connection);

    // use exception handling if necessary
    if(!isset($result)) throw new customException('pk not found');

    return $result;
}   

// Typical execution
$connection = db_connect();

try
{
    $result = select_pk($connection, $pk);
}
catch(customException $e)
{
    /*** do something ***/
}
```

Although this template is, so far, working fine (single server), I have the impression that:

- the preparation for next query is overcomplicated (`mysqli_free_result`, `mysqli_more_results` and `mysqli_next_result`)
- it does not deal properly with errors

**Question**

Any comments or advice on how to improve this template?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not deal properly with errors" please?

Comment: It is just an impression. My guess is that I'm simply not dealing with some important types of errors (maybe communication types of errors?). But I'm not sure what these errors would be, therefore I'm not able to elaborate much better than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first I would give a generalized answer that likely would help other people stumbling upon this question and then review the particular case of yours.

I asked myself exactly the same question a long time ago and eventually came to a set of solutions that ease the database operations using mysqli.

#### Mysqli connection

I have doubts about storing a connection code in a function. It asks to be misused. A connection to a single database should be established strictly **once** during a single HTTP request/php instance. but a function's purpose to be called multiple times. It would be better to put the connection code in a file instead, and then just include this file in your code in a single place.

I've got a canonical [mysqli connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect) that deals with a whole lot of problems before they even appear. So, instead of  `function db_connect()` let's create a file called `mysqli.php` and put the following code there

```
<?php

$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    $conn->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
unset($host, $db, $user, $pass, $charset); // we don't need them anymore
```

Among other solutions it will *translate mysql errors into PHP exceptions* which is, basically all you need in order to deal with errors.

#### Running prepared queries

The next problem is rather elaborate code required for the prepared queries in mysqli. To deal with it i wrote a [mysqli helper function](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/simple) that eases the process dramatically.

> note that although your current approach with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is *technically* safe, it is frowned upon never the less, as it's a subject of human errors of all sorts. Better stick to prepared statements for all queries that involve a PHP variable as input.

So next solution would be a helper function like this

```
function prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params = [], $types = "")
{
    if (!$params) {
        return $mysqli->query($sql);
    }
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
}
```

and you will get a tool that will make prepared statements as smooth as regular queries

#### Calling stored procedures with mysqli

Stored procedures are not easy because of a quirk: *every call returns more than one resultset* and therefore we need to loop over them. We cannot avoid it but at least we can automatize this process too. We can write a function that encapsulates all the resultset jiggery-pokery.

```
function prepared_call($mysqli, $sql, $params = [], $types = ""): array
{
    $resource = prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types);
    $data = $resource->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    while(mysqli_more_results($mysqli)) mysqli_next_result($mysqli);
    return $data;
}
```

#### A specifik function to call for a PK

And finally we can rewrite your `select_pk()` function

```
function select_pk($mysqli, string $pk): array
{
    $data = prepared_call($mysqli, "CALL select__pk(?)", $pk);
    return $data[0] ?? null;
}
```

I am not really sure we need an exception here though:

```
include 'mysqli.php';

$result = select_pk($mysqli, $pk);
if (!$result) {
    /*** do something ***/
}
```

Comment: Mind to explain why escaped in `\mysqli_sql_exception`? Something related to namespaces? Typo?

Comment: > _"Among other solutions it [`mysqli.php`] will translate mysql errors into PHP exceptions"_ Considering that this file `throw` new exceptions, should it be called via a standard `require`? Or should it be called via `try/catch` statement?

Comment: > _"it is frowned upon never the less, as it's a subject of human errors of all sorts."_ Mind to provide one example of such human errors that stored procedures are vulnerable while prepared statements are not?

Comment: > _"`function prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params = [], $types = "")`"_ If I understood properly, this means that your query statements are stored in the PHP files instead of in the MySQL. In this case, AFAIK, queries stored in MySQL (ex: as stored procedures) are compiled+optimized only once which cause some benefits in performance compared to storing the queries in PHP. Therefore, I'm wondering: are there some performance penalties using such helper function?

Comment: Good questions. 1. Yes \ is a namespace proof code. 2. Always just a standard require. Basically you only use try catch if have an idea what to write in a catch block. 3. Placeholders in a prepared statements protect from injections 100%, escaping and procedures don't. But that's too wide a topic to discuss in comments. 4. Whatever performance benefit of peocedures is a sort of a delusion. May be in a some extreme case but a simple pk lookup is definitely not among them. Dunno your background but procs are used may be in 0.0001% of all PHP scripts in the world. The rest is sql

Comment: Further reading, try catch: https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting , escaping / placeholders: https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection